# Does not enable a menustrip item when the folder has files with

Tags: vb.net, winforms

My form's `Load` event handler checks if a folder is available (if not, it creates it) and if available checks if there are files with a specific extension. If there's at least one file with that extension, it will enable an option on a `MenuStrip` (referred to as `QuickLoadMenuStripItem`).

The problem is when it checks a folder when it's on the user's folder, it does not work, regardless if there is or not. It executes the code normally, but it always gives false. Here's the code:

```
Public Class BaseForm1

    Private Sub BaseForm1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim ImportFolder As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + "\Immortal Sins\Saves\"
        If (Not Directory.Exists(ImportFolder)) Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory(ImportFolder)
            QuickStartToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
        Else
            Directory.GetFiles(ImportFolder)
            For Each tempstring As String In ImportFolder
                If tempstring.Contains(".isgsf") Then
                    QuickStartToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
                Else
                   QuickStartToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

For reference, it checks on C:\Users\\Immortal Sins\Saves. The files have the .isgsf extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do:

```
Private Sub BaseForm1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim ImportFolder As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile), "Immortal Sins\Saves\")
    If (Not Directory.Exists(ImportFolder)) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(ImportFolder)
        QuickStartToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
    Else
        QuickStartToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = (Directory.GetFiles(ImportFolder, "*.isgsf").Length > 0)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It works, though I had to set the ImportFolder variable as Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + "\Immortal Sins\Saves\", since your version checked on \Immortal Sins\Saves instead of C:\Users\<Username>\Immortal Sins\Saves. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry, take of the leading backslash and it should work.  Edited code above.

Answer (score 0):

You're not storing the file list on `ImportFolder` when retrieving the content at `Directory.GetFiles(ImportFolder)`

Also, you're not checking the file extension. You're checking if the file contains a certain string.

Try this instead

```
Dim ImportFolder As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + "\Immortal Sins\Saves\"
If (Not Directory.Exists(ImportFolder)) Then
    Directory.CreateDirectory(ImportFolder)
    QuickStartToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
Else
    Dim fileEntries As String() = Directory.GetFiles(ImportFolder)
    For Each file As String In fileEntries
        Dim extension As String = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file)
        If extension = "isgsf" Then
            QuickStartToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
            Exit For 'Once a .isgsf is found the next files should't be checked
        Else
            QuickStartToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
        End If
    Next
End If
```